# error in pathlib module in python when Iam using vscode

Tags: python, pathlib

I'd add path form pathlib to my vscode but whenever I call it's modules like path.stat I have an error,and vscode  won't allow me to use () for calling

```
from pathlib import Path 

path=Path("enum/__init__.py")

pri=path.stat
print(pri)
```

the error is:bound method Path.read_bytes of WindowsPath('enum/**init**.py')

Comment: and whats the error? Please edit your post and include the error message.

Comment: Please include full text of error in your post

Comment: That's not a valid Windows path, change it to `r"enum\__init__.py"`

Comment: no difrrent I got same eroor withr"enum\__init__.py"

Answer (score 0):

Unix systems uses slash as separator (**/**) in filenames.
On Microsoft Windows backslash (**\**) is used.
So, your code should be edited as follows:

```
from pathlib import Path 

path=Path(r"enum\__init__.py")

pri=path.stat
print(pri)
```